# Extract date from string with only 2 digit years

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to extract a date from a cell, for example, **??/??/????**. My code pull the date from a string like **??/??/????** and **??.??.????**, but I need to extract years with 2 only digits in.

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(R25;"../../....");MID(R25;FIND("/";R25;1)-2;10);
IF(REGEXMATCH(R25;"..\...\.....");REGEXREPLACE(MID(R25;FIND(".??.????";R25;1)-2;10);"\.";"/");""))
```

Does someone have an idea?
Extract the date from the right cell string.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wWVa.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 ok, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5; 
 "\d+.\d+.\d{4}"); "."; "/")*1; "dd/mm/yy")))
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, i edited the post to clarify.

Comment: @voidalzk updated try now

Comment: =IF(REGEXMATCH(R26;"../../....");MID(R26;FIND("/";R26;1)-2;10);
IF(REGEXMATCH(R26;"..\...\.....");REGEXREPLACE(MID(R26;FIND(".??.????";R26;1)-2;10);IF(REGEXMATCH(R26;".??.??");TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(R26; "\d+.\d+.\d{4}"); "."; "/")*1; "dd/mm/yy")))))
I implemented in this way, but is returning "false", any ideia?

Comment: @voidalzk try: `=IF(REGEXMATCH(R26,"../../...."), MID(R26,FIND("/",R26,1)-2,10), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(R26,"..\...\....."),REGEXREPLACE(MID(R26,FIND(".??.????",R26,1)-2,10)),
 IF(REGEXMATCH(R26,".??.??"),TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(R26, "\d+.\d+.\d{4}"), ".", "/")*1, "dd/mm/yy"), )))`